# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments when trying to pin some locations on a MapView

Tags: swiftui

I'm getting this error and can't figure out why.
Can you help me?

```
struct Locs: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name = String()
    let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let alarm = Int()
    let state = Int()
    let radius = Int()
    
    
}

struct MapView: View {
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 5.55613, longitude: 95.3218), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    let annotations = [
            Locs(name: "Sultan Hotel", coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 5.55739, longitude: 95.3208), alarm: 0, state: 0, radius: 1),
            Locs(name: "Paparon Pizza Lhokseumawe", coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 5.17837, longitude: 97.1484), alarm: 0, state: 1, radius: 2)
    
    
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide default values outside of the `init`, unless you want the properties to be declared as a `var`.

Either:

1. Don't have default values (unless it won't change and not needed for memberwise `init`)

```
struct Locs: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let alarm: Int
    let state: Int
    let radius: Int
}
```

2. Have default values with a custom `init`

```
struct Locs: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let alarm: Int
    let state: Int
    let radius: Int

    init(name: String = "some default name", coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, alarm: Int, state: Int, radius: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.coord = coord
        self.alarm = alarm
        self.state = state
        self.radius = radius
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now